# How do I display a "Thank You" message after submitting a Webform 3.x form?

Tags: 6, webforms

I recently upgraded a Drupal 5 site to Drupal 6.  This upgrade also entailed upgrading the [Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform) from version 2 to version 3.

I have a very simple webform setup that asks for a name and email address to sign up for a newsletter.  Before upgrading, the webform administration area had a textarea labeled **Confirmation message or redirect URL**, but I no longer see this option.

When the form is submitted, it just reloads the form with empty values.  The form is submitted properly, but I would like to be able to present a "Thank You" message instead of reloading the form page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the webform node, click the Webform tab, then the Form Settings sub-tab. There should be a large textarea labeled "Confirmation message".

If you are on node 1, the URL would be example.com/node/1/webform/configure.

Comment: I don't have any sub-tabs when I am on the Webform tab.

Comment: Make sure you have Webform 6.x-3.9 installed. I *just* installed it on a test site and it looked [like this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/01acsa61c).

Comment: I do have 3.9 installed and I do not see any of those sub-tabs.  I think it has to do with our theme because I do see them using the Bluemarine theme.

Comment: I was able to fix my theme by following the advice of **rank** here: http://drupal.org/node/329616